# In D3.js, how to only add a comma on numbers with 5+ digits?

Tags: d3.js

In D3.js (v5) you can specify formatting for numbers to add commas every three digits:

```
d3.format(',')(1000) // "1,000"
```

Or ensure it doesn't:

```
d3.format('d')(1000) // "1000"
```

But I'd like to add a comma only if the number has five or more digits, so:

```
d3.format( ? )(1000)  // 1000
d3.format( ? )(10000) // 10,000
```

What would my missing format specifier (`?`) be?

Comment: write a multiFormat handler like here https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just keep it simple and wrap the logic in your own function:

```js
function myFormatter(d){
 return (""+d).length > 4 ? d3.format(',')(d) : d3.format('d')(d);
}

console.log(myFormatter(1000), myFormatter(10000))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks Mark! One thought I've added... instead of `(""+d).length` I might use `(""+d3.format('.0f')(d)).length`, so that it would still work if the number has decimal places.